# IntentService Returning False When Checking if Service is Running

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice

I am using an `IntentService` to call on a webservice.

How I am calling to start the intent service:

```
 if (isMyConServiceRunning(TaskService.class,context) == false) {
            Log.d(TAG,"STARTING TaskService");
            context.startService(TasksIntentUploadDownload);
        }
```

isMyConServiceRunning method:

```
 private static boolean isMyConServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass,Context context) 
    {
        try {
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
                if (serviceClass.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).contains(service.service.getClassName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
        return false;
    }
```

`isMyConServiceRunning` is always returning `false` (the service is not running) and thus service is being started multiple times but I noticed that when I override the method `OnStartCommand` and place the webservice call in `OnStartCommand` and not in `OnHandleIntent` and making `OnStartCommand` return `START_STICKY`, then `isMyConServiceRunning` will recognize that the service is running.

Is it bad to run tasks in `OnStartCommand`?

If yes, how can I fix the multiple calls to run `IntentService`?

Comment: why are you checking for service already running ?

Comment: i am checking if service is not running then if its not i start the service

Comment: and the above is returning false all the time

Comment: The purpose of intent service is to do some work and close itself unlike services which needs to be stopped. you can start intent service using Alarm Manager to start itself after every 10 mins.

Comment: that is true, but this is not my question.. i am just checking if it is running or not (which it is) but its returning false...and my question is why

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be:

in your service class:

```
private void sendMessageStart() {

        Intent intent = new Intent("Service-Started");
        intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);

    }
    private void sendMessageStop() {

        Intent intent = new Intent("Service-Stopped");
        intent.putExtra("message", "This is my message!");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

in the class you want to check if the service is running or not:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiverStart = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

        }
    };
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiverStop = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Get extra data included in the Intent
            String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");


            } 
        } 
    };
```